# How to search within Linked list in c++

Tags: visual-c++, linked-list

```
void search(library *start)
{
    system("cls");
    char author[20],title[20];
    cout<<"Enter Book title and its Author name respectively to Search in stock\n";
    cin>>title>>author;

    while(start!=NULL)
    {
        if(title==start->title)
        {
            if(author==start->author)
            {
                cout<<"\n\nBook is In Stock\n";
                cout<<"It Cost Rs"<<start->price;
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    cout<<"\n\nSEARCH IS NOT IN STOCK\n";
}
```

Comment: it doesn't show anything once after taking inputs by user, only show the black screen with underscore line....

Answer (score 0):

`title==start->title` compares pointers. `title==start->title` does not compare the contents of the memory that the pointers point to.

Use `std::string` (in `<string>`) for strings, instead of C-style character arrays.

`cin>>title>>author` will go horribly wrong if the entered title is longer than 19 chqaracters. Again, use `std::string` (in `<string>`) for strings, instead of C-style character arrays.